# The element type "tag" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</tag>"

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

The code below contains an error.

> The element type `"xs:sequence"` must be terminated by the matching
> end-tag `""`, at 37:5, ie line 35 column 5.

I think it's referring to this:

```
 </xs:element>
```

but I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.joe.bloggs.org/2020/XMLSchema" >

 

<xs:element name="Employee_Data" type="EmployeeDataType" />

<xs:complexType name="EmployeeDataType">

  <xs:sequence>

   <xs:element ref="Employee" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />

  </xs:sequence>

</xs:complexType>

 

<xs:element name="Employee" type="EmployeeType" />

<xs:complexType name="EmployeeType">

  <xs:sequence >

   <xs:element ref="Name" />

   <xs:element ref="Age" />

   <xs:simpleType>
   <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
   <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
   <xs:maxInclusive value="120"/>
   </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
   </xs:element>

  

   <xs:element ref="Start Date" />

   <xs:element ref="Annual Income” />

         <xs:complexType>

            <xs:simpleContent>

                <xs:extension base="xs:double">

                    <xs:attribute name="currency">

                        <xs:simpleType>

                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">

                                <xs:enumeration value="Pounds" />

                                <xs:enumeration value="Euros" />

                                <xs:enumeration value="USdollars" />

                            </xs:restriction>

                        </xs:simpleType>

                    </xs:attribute>

                </xs:extension>

            </xs:simpleContent>

        </xs:complexType>

    </xs:element>

   <xs:element ref="Department" />

   <xs:simpleType>
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
   <xs:enumeration value="Sales"/>
   <xs:enumeration value="Marketing"/>
   <xs:enumeration value="IT"/>
   </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
   </xs:element>

 

<xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />

<xs:element name="Start Date" type="xs:date" />

 

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Has your question been answered?  If so, please [**accept**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/234215) an answer.  If not, please ask a follow-up question to clarify.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the error,

> The element type `"tag"` must be terminated by the matching
> end-tag `"</tag>"`

is a basic XML well-formedness error beneath the XSD level.  It occurs anytime the XML parser encounters a closing `tag` for which it hasn't previously encountered a matching opening `tag`.  (In your case, `tag` = `xs:sequence`, and the error message seems to have lost the closing `tag`, probably due to copy-and-paste markup mistake along the way.)

To resolve, scan back to the opening tag that seemed intended to be paired with the offending closing tag.  Resolution might involve adding, relocating, or repairing the start tag, or removing, relocating, or repairing the end tag.  In your case, the intended start tag has to be repaired not to be self-closing.

Change

```
  <xs:element ref="Age" />
```

to

```
  <xs:element ref="Age" >
```

You'll find that there are a slew of further issues to resolve, including additional instances of the above problem further down the document, the use of `”` where `"` is required, and the use of the wrong namespace for XSD elements, the use of spaces in element names, the use of `xs:element/@ref` where `xs:element/@name` should instead be used, and having to close out additional XSD elements.

### Fully repaired XSD

To maximize learning, I strongly recommend that you work through the above issues independently.  If you find that you've reached another impasse, here is a fully repaired XSD to consult:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
  <xs:element name="Employee_Data" type="EmployeeDataType" />
  <xs:complexType name="EmployeeDataType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="Employee" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="Employee" type="EmployeeType" />
  <xs:complexType name="EmployeeType">
    <xs:sequence >
      <xs:element name="Name" />
      <xs:element name="Age" >
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="120"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="StartDate" />
      <xs:element name="AnnualIncome">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:double">
              <xs:attribute name="currency">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="Pounds" />
                    <xs:enumeration value="Euros" />
                    <xs:enumeration value="USdollars" />
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:attribute>
            </xs:extension>
          </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Department">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Sales"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Marketing"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="IT"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```